# Python - Called Script is searching for a file in the Calling Script's directory

Tags: python, django

I have the following structure

```
C:\Users\dhiwakarr\workspace\BasicRegressionOnJoker\create&&bkp\script1.py
```

`script1.py` will call a function/method defined in `script2.py` which is located in

```
C:\Users\dhiwakarr\workspace\basics\script2.py
```

The problem is `script2.py` will make use of an `XML File (create.xml)` which is located in the same folder as `script2.py`. But when I call this method IN `script2.py` FROM `script1.py`. I get the following error,

```
execute: Error 0x304: Failed to read the input file[createsc.xml].
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create&&bkp.py", line 19, in <module>
    CreateSC.create()
```

My guess is that the called script (`script2.py`) is searching for this file in the calling script (`script1.py`). How do I make the method of script2.py called in script1.py make it search in its own directory ?

**UPDATE**

script1.sc

```
import subprocess,sys,getopt,codecs,re,string
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
sys.path.insert(0,r'C:\Users\dhiwakarr\workspace\basics')
import Login
import script2
#import script3

try:
#First call the login script to login 
    print('Login started')
    Login.login()
    print('Create Subclient')
    script2.create()
```

....

**script2.py**

```
import subprocess,sys,os,inspect
from sys import stdout
from _winapi import NULL


def create():
    '''
    A text file with information about the Client,Storage Policy,Backupset,Subclient & Content of each subclient must be given as seen in sample-create.txt
    '''
    inputfile = r'C:\Users\dhiwakarr\workspace\create.txt'
    finp = open(inputfile,'r')
    path = str(os.getcwd())
    print('Current Working Path is -- '+path)
    for line in finp:
        line=line.rstrip('\n')
           ....
    # Creating the Subclient
            subprocess.check_call(["C:\\Program Files\\CommVault\\Simpana\\Base\\qoperation.exe", 'execute', '-af', `'createsc.xml',` '-appName', "'File System'",'-clientName', client,'-backupsetName', bset, '-subclientName', scname, '-storagePolicyName', storagepolicy])
        else:
```

See the line subprocess.check_call(["... it fails to read the XML.

Comment: so the output of print os.getcwd is C:\Users\dhiwakarr\workspace\ ?

Comment: alternatively you might use the absolute path to .xml in the subprocess call, to overwrite eventual default paths in qoperation.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information given is sparse and more code would be helpful.

In general when calling a script from the command line, the base path will be the path, the shell is directed to not the path of calling.

To get information about where your script is looking for files, insert

```
print os.getcwd()
```

at the appropriate places (before open or file command). You need to have imported 'os' from the battery pack though.

Furthermore, to get better understanding of the underlying problem, using a

```
try: 
    f = open(f) 
    …
except IOError as e:
    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise
```

might give better understanding of the underlying problem.

> > your added code information:

Changes of sys.Path (.extend; .insert) will not change the directory for file I/O. sys.Path is directing the module loader only. Use os.chdir or relative paths for file I/O. Use the above print os.getcwd() method get further information about where your code is looking for the .xml file.

Comment: I', using os.chdir() to get it done. However I use os.chdir() in the called script's code